# Which languages are available for elementary?

Tags: language

I'm trying to find a list of all language packs usable within elementary OS. Is there a complete list somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Visit the [Languages @ elementary Weblate](https://l10n.elementary.io/languages/) to get an overview of the languages supported in elementary OS. If you want to view the support on a per app basis, go to the [Projects @ elementary Weblate](https://l10n.elementary.io/projects/). If you want to improve the translations, give this [Translation Guide](https://elementary.io/docs/translation-guide#translation-guide) a read.